# How to make the background image behind the transparent SliverAppBar?

Tags: flutter, dart, appbar, sliverappbar

I'm a beginner to Flutter and I have a problem with the screen background, it was filled fully when I used the `AppBar`, but when I changed it to `SliverAppBar`, the top bar becomes empty and the image starts after it, how to solve this because most of the issues when I searched, are regarding the `SliverAppBar` background itself, not the main background

Also, how to control the location of the `leading` image (logo) without its size being changed, because when I change the location using `margin`, it becomes smaller

```
// ignore_for_file: deprecated_member_use, unnecessary_const

import 'package:decorated_icon/decorated_icon.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) => [
          SliverAppBar(
            actions: [
              Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 15, 12, 0),
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: const DecoratedIcon(
                        Icons.notifications,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                        size: 30.0,
                        shadows: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            blurStyle: BlurStyle.normal,
                            blurRadius: 7.0,
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                            offset: Offset.zero,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              // ),
            ],
            leading: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 0, 0),
              child: const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage('images/logo.png'),
                  height: 500,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
          ),
        ],
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                image: const DecorationImage(
                  image: const AssetImage("images/background.jpg"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

return Container(
height:screenheight,
width:screenwidth,
child:Scaffold()
);

Answer (score 0):

Implemented like this in my code. Hope this helps you as well.

```
SliverAppBar(
                        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                        expandedHeight: 310,
                        elevation: 0,
                        floating: true,
                        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                        centerTitle: true,
                        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                        leading: new IconButton(
                          icon: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Get.theme.primaryColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                                blurRadius: 20,
                              ),
                            ]),
                            child: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Get.theme.hintColor),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () => {Get.back()},
                        ),
                        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                          collapseMode: CollapseMode.parallax,
                          background: Obx(() {
                            return Stack(
                              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                buildCarouselSlider(_eService),
                              ],
                            );
                          }),
                        ).marginOnly(bottom: 50),
                      ),
```